# setOnLongClickListener on framelayout not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Bellow mentioned is the code where i am registering framelayout for long click listener event.

```
private void createActivityLayout(Fragment fragment) 
{
    FrameLayout frameLayout =     (FrameLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.professional_pa_frame_layout, null, false);

    frameLayout.setClickable(true);

    frameLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() 
    {
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) 
        {
            if (actionMode == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            actionMode = view.startActionMode(actionModelCallback);
            view.setSelected(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(id, fragment, tag).commit();
}
```

The fragment internally contains a series of edittext instances or a single imageview instances.

Whenever a long click is performed on framelayout, i guess the contextual action bar for edittext is displayed. I think the event is captured by editext and different contextual action bar is displayed. PFA image of the contextual action bar displayed whenever i get a long click event inside framelayout.

[image]

How can i capture long click event on my framelayout as a whole without displaying contextual action bar for its internal views. xml code written below is of the contextual action bar that i want to be displayed for my framelayout.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_discard_notes"
    android:icon="@drawable/discard_note"
    android:title="@string/action_discard_notes"
    android:showAsAction="always" 
    android:orderInCategory="1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **ActionModeCallback** of Edittext so CAB aborted and call Framelayout long click like below code...

```
    m_editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode p_mode, Menu p_menu)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode p_mode, Menu p_menu)
                {                   
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode p_mode)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode p_mode, MenuItem p_item)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

You need to return false in **onCreateActionMode** for abort CAB(contextual action bar).